# Source a vector of characters

Tags: r

The following script works perfectly well. Still, I would like to know if it possible to source directly the vector x.

```
x <- c("print (\"Hallo world\")", "print (\"(Just an example)\")")
temporary_file <- tempfile()
write(x, file = temporary_file )
source(temporary_file)
```

Comment: It's better to use something like `dput`/`dump` or, even better: to save an object as an RDS file (using `saveRDS`) than rely on `source`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x <- c("print (\"Hallo world\")", "print (\"(Just an example)\")");
eval(parse(text=x));
## [1] "Hallo world"
## [1] "(Just an example)"
```

Comment: Thank you ! (I thought I tried myself all combinations of "parse" and "eval".)

Comment: Another variation is `eval(parse(textConnection(x)))`